# Edge-disjoint shortest paths

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a simple connected graph. Let a, b, c, d be four distinct vertices of G.

Is there a way to partition the above four vertices to two pairs, so that the two shortest paths between the vertices of each pair are edge-disjoint?

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be possible in all cases. You might want to add some context to this question; right now, I'm not sure why this is an interesting problem. 

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Just pick the two paths (not necessarily edge disjoint) in G of shortest total length which together join the four vertices into two pairs.  If they contained a common edge, you could remove that edge from both paths (changing which vertices are connected to which) to obtain a pair of paths of shorter total length.  The resulting paths must be shortest paths between the pairs of vertices they connect.  <strike>(I assume I'm allowed to pick any shortest path between two vertices, if there's more than one.)</strike>  Any pair of shortest paths between the same pairs of vertices has the same total length, so by the same argument the two paths of the pair must be edge-disjoint.